# How to replace a pattern start with {| to end of string (multi line), if there is no |} inside

Tags: python, regex

What I need is to manipulate bad-formated wiki code.
I have:

```
s = '''
whatever...
{|
line1
|}

whatever...
{|
lineXXX

'''
```

Now I want to delete from {| to end, if no |} inside.

The result I want is:

```
'''
whatever...
{|
line1
|}

whatever...

'''
```

I tried:

```
re.sub('{|[^(\|\})]*$', '\n',s)
```

but failed.

How to do this?

Comment: The first block starts with `|{` and the second starts with `{|` - is it a typo?

Comment: typo, corrected

Comment: Ok, got it, you just need to remove the last `{|`-`no_|}_inside`-`endOfstring`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your pattern contains an unescaped `|` that becomes an alternation operator. Then, `[^(\|\})]*` does not negate a *sequence* of `|}`, it just matches 0+ chars other than `(`, `|`, `}` and `)`.

You may use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (requiring a `re.DOTALL` modifier):

```
{\|(?:(?!\|}).)*$
```

or its unroll-the-loop variant (not requiring the `re.DOTALL` modifier):

```
{\|[^|]*(?:\|(?!})[^|]*)*$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zY3bC5/3) or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/zY3bC5/4).

**Pattern details**:

- `{\|` - a literal `{|` text
- `(?:(?!\|}).)*` - a tempered greedy token that matches any character (`.`) that does not start a `|}` sequence (OR the unrolled variant is `[^|]*(?:\|(?!})[^|]*)*` - 0+ non-`|`s followed with 0+ sequences of `|` not followed with `}` and then 0+ non-`|`s)
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ai3C9v):

```
import re
s = '''
whatever...
{|
line1
|}

whatever...
{|
lineXXX

'''
res = re.sub(r'{\|(?:(?!\|}).)*$', '', s, flags=re.S)
print(res)
```

Comment: I have updated all the demos, I do not know why I thought you need to remove all `{|...|}` blocks.